# Converting from void * to float

Tags: pointers

I have a pointer to some location in memory passed in, `void *dataLoc`.

Some program is transferring memory there as a bunch of `unsigned char`s where 0x00 is 0 and 0xFF is one.

I want to be able to pull, say, every 4th char and convert it to the `float` of what number is supposed to be represented. But I'm having trouble understanding how I get from a `void *` to an array of `char[]` to an array of `float[]`.

My initial thought was to do something like

```
for(i=0,i<100,i++){
    floatArray[i] = (float)(*((unsigned char *)dataLoc[4*i])) / 255;
}
```

1. the `void *` is cast to a `char *`.
2. the next 4th char is selected from the for loop
3. the `*` dereferences the char pointer, which should give me an `unsigned char`,
4. the `float` should change the `char` into a `float`, but a `float` representation of the number I want *255
5. I divide by 255 to get the fraction I want.

This fails, because I get the error "pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic
    'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type and beyond this, I'm not really confident that the rest of that line will work out the way I would like.

Can someone advise the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good that you had warnings enabled.

`dataLoc[4*i]` occurs before `(unsigned char *)dataLoc` and leads to "`pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic ...`"

Cast to `unsigned char *` first.

Also remove extra level of `*`.  The following is type `unsigned char`

```
((unsigned char *)dataLoc)[4*i]
```

Fixed:

```
  void *  dataLoc;
  float floatArray[100];

  // for(i=0,i<100,i++){  Use ';', not ','
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
      // Cast to `unsigned char *` before using `[]`
      // * not needed here ---v  
      floatArray[i] = (float)( (   ((unsigned char *)dataLoc)  [4*i])) / 255;
  }
```

or

```
  for (int i=0; i<100 ;i++) {
    unsigned char value = ((unsigned char *)dataLoc)[4*i];
    floatArray[i] = value / 255.0f;
  }
```

Comment: To add to that, the error was about that you can't do pointer arithmetic on void pointers.In your case it means the compiler does not know what dataLoc[4*i] means.
And why not use some more lines to make it more clear. Lines are cheap, developer's time is expensive :)

Comment: @foolo OK, added alternate coding.